# Is it possible to show the default Windows progress dialog using SWT

Tags: java, dialog, swt, progress-bar, progressdialog

Can I display the default Windows progress dialog using SWT? Here's the dialog that I'm referring to:

[image]

I've seen some implementations of it in .Net but was curious about doing the same in Java.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [ProgressMonitorDialog](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/dialogs/ProgressMonitorDialog.html) (it's not exactly the same as the Window's one).

Here is usefull [link](http://sureshkrishna.wordpress.com/2008/03/15/jface-dialogs-which-one-is-right-for-you/) to find the standard dialogs of JFace/SWT.

Comment: He asked for the same as Windows' one.